# Help with optimization of Reduce/Solve function

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning, simplifying-expressions

I have a set of vectors in $3$D  as shown below,

```
v1 = {1, 1, 1}/Sqrt[3];
v2 = {1, -1, -1}/Sqrt[3];
v3 = {-1, 1, -1}/Sqrt[3];
v4 = {-1, -1, 1}/Sqrt[3];
r1 = a1 v1 + a2 v2 + a3 v3;
r2 = b1 v1 + b2 v2 + b3 v3;
r3 = c1 v1 + c2 v2 + c3 v3;
r4 = d1 v1 + d2 v2 + d3 v3;
```

Based on some constraints on these vectors, I obtained the values for `a1,a2,...,d2,d3`, in terms of other variables `t11,...,t24`.(The relations are given at the end of this question.)

Now, given `W`,

```
W = 1/2 (Sqrt[Dot[r1 + r2 - r3 - r4, r1 + r2 - r3 - r4]] + 
 Sqrt[Dot[r1 - r2 + r3 - r4, r1 - r2 + r3 - r4]] + 
 Sqrt[Dot[r1 - r2 - r3 + r4, r1 - r2 - r3 + r4]] - 
 1/2 (4 + r1 . v1 + r2 . v2 + r3 . v3 + r4 . v4));
```

I want to evaluate the following expression,

```
Reduce[{D[W, t11] == 0, D[W, t12] == 0, D[W, t22] == 0, 
D[W, t13] == 0, D[W, t23] == 0, D[W, t14] == 0, 
D[W, t24] == 0}, {t11, t12, t22, t13, t23, t14, t24}]
```

This is taking too long to compute in my system. Is there any known way to optimize this problem?

Here are the relations between the variables `a1,a2,...,d2,d3`, and  `t11,...,t24`

```
 a1 = t11 - 1/12 Sqrt[24 - 27 t11^2 - 18 t11 t21 - 27 t21^2] + 
      1/8 (t11 + 3 t21 - 1/3 Sqrt[24 - 27 t11^2 - 18 t11 t21 - 
      27 t21^2]);
 a2 = 3/8 (t11 + 3 t21 - 
      1/3 Sqrt[24 - 27 t11^2 - 18 t11 t21 - 27 t21^2]);
 a3 = -(1/4) Sqrt[24 - 27 t11^2 - 18 t11 t21 - 27 t21^2];
 b1 = t12 - 1/12 Sqrt[24 - 27 t12^2 - 18 t12 t22 - 27 t22^2] + 
      1/8 (t12 + 3 t22 - 1/3 Sqrt[24 - 27 t12^2 - 18 t12 t22 - 
      27 t22^2]);
 b2 = 3/8 (t12 + 3 t22 - 
      1/3 Sqrt[24 - 27 t12^2 - 18 t12 t22 - 27 t22^2]);
 b3 = -(1/4) Sqrt[24 - 27 t12^2 - 18 t12 t22 - 27 t22^2];
 c1 = t13 - 1/12 Sqrt[24 - 27 t13^2 - 18 t13 t23 - 27 t23^2] + 
      1/8 (t13 + 3 t23 - 
      1/3 Sqrt[24 - 27 t13^2 - 18 t13 t23 - 27 t23^2]);
 c2 = 3/8 (t13 + 3 t23 - 
      1/3 Sqrt[24 - 27 t13^2 - 18 t13 t23 - 27 t23^2]);
 c3 = -(1/4) Sqrt[24 - 27 t13^2 - 18 t13 t23 - 27 t23^2];
 d1 = t14 - 1/12 Sqrt[24 - 27 t14^2 - 18 t14 t24 - 27 t24^2] + 
      1/8 (t14 + 3 t24 - 1/3 Sqrt[24 - 27 t14^2 - 18 t14 t24 - 
      27 t24^2]);
 d2 = 3/8 (t14 + 3 t24 - 
      1/3 Sqrt[24 - 27 t14^2 - 18 t14 t24 - 27 t24^2]);
 d3 = -(1/4) Sqrt[24 - 27 t14^2 - 18 t14 t24 - 27 t24^2];
```

All the variables are real. Also note that I'm taking derivative of `W` w.r.t every variable of the form `tij` except `t21` and setting them to zero. I'm tryin
g to find the extreme values of `W` in terms of those variables. I've also tried fixing `t21` before the `Reduce` operation, with no luck. I have also tried this with `Solve`.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is `t13No^2`  a typo in the code?  See last block of code, solution to `c1` inside the `Sqrt`

Comment: so sorry for that. It is a typo. Ill edit it right away. Thanks

Comment: Many thanks as well!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looking for a zero of the derivatives, you could minimize/maximize your function `W` numerically.

I've extracted the constraints for making all intermediate variables real:

```
With[{T21 = 0.3},
  NMinimize[{W, 
             t11^2 <= 1 && t12^2 <= 1 && t22^2 <= 1 &
             t13^2 <= 1 && t23^2 <= 1 && t14^2 <= 1 &&
             t24^2 <= 1 &&
             3 t11^2 + 2 t11 t21 + 3 t21^2 <= 8/3 && 
             3 t12^2 + 2 t12 t22 + 3 t22^2 <= 8/3 && 
             3 t13^2 + 2 t13 t23 + 3 t23^2 <= 8/3 && 
             3 t14^2 + 2 t14 t24 + 3 t24^2 <= 8/3} /. t21 -> T21,
            {t11, t12, t22, t13, t23, t14, t24},
            Method -> "RandomSearch"]]

(*    {-1., {t11 -> -0.168568,
             t12 -> -0.168568, t22 -> 0.3,
             t13 -> -0.168568, t23 -> 0.3,
             t14 -> -0.168568, t24 -> 0.3}}    *)
```

This minimum looks very symmetric and can be a starting point for an analytic search, where $t_{11}=t_{12}=t_{13}=t_{14}$ and $t_{21}=t_{22}=t_{23}=t_{24}$.

Comment: Hmm..interesting...How did you find out the new constraints?

Comment: You have terms like $\sqrt{-27 t_{11}^2-18 t_{11} t_{21}-27 t_{21}^2+24}$ and similar in your expression. For this to be real-valued, we need $-27 t_{11}^2-18 t_{11} t_{21}-27 t_{21}^2+24\ge0$, which after division by 9 is the same as saying $3 t_{11}^2+2 t_{11} t_{21}+3 t_{21}^2\le8/3$. Also, `RegionPlot[24 - 27 t11^2 - 18 t11 t21 - 27 t21^2 >= 0, {t11, -1, 1}, {t21, -1, 1}]` shows what's going on. In fact all parameters must be in $[-1,1]$.